# self with two arguments using dot syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, self

I have looked through a lot of questions and I am still unable to understand this syntax in Big Nerd Ranch.

```
-(void) setContainedItem:(BNR *)containedItem
{
  _containedItem = containedItem;
  self.containedItem.container = self;
}
```

Here `self.containedItem.container = self`, does it mean

```
[[self containedItem]container:self]
```

which is equivalent to

```
[[self setContainedItem]container:self]
```

I am confused and trying to get a way around this.
Please kindly explain.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't one construct — it's two property accesses. Just read it from left to right with each dot its own operation. We aren't assigning anything to `self.containedItem`, so we're just getting its value. OK, that's one operation. Then we set the `container` property of the object returned by that operation to `self`. So this is roughly equivalent to:

```
[[self containedItem] setContainer:self]
```

Comment: Great, but containedItem is syntesises to be like this:
@property containedItem = _containedItem

therefore [self containedItem] should mean setContainedItem, not the value? This is the only thing i wish to vl;arify

Comment: I got it, it is [self containedItem] which means it runs the method containedItem, yes.